# Excel Automation in WebBrowser Control

Tags: vb.net, excel, automation, vba

I am using the following code to display an Excel Spreadsheet in a WebBrowser Control in VB.net 2010 Express.

```
Option Explicit On
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports System.Data
Public Class CustomerService
      Dim oDocument As Object
      Dim oXL As Excel.Application
      Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
      Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
      Dim oRng As Excel.Range
      Private Sub CustomerService_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      WebBrowser1.Navigate(quoteFile)
End Sub
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NavigateComplete2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NavigateComplete2Event) Handles WebBrowser1.NavigateComplete2
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oXL As New Excel.Application
    oDocument = e.pDisp.Document
    With oDocument.Application.CommandBars("Standard")
        .Position = 4 '[msoBarFloating]
        .Visible = True
    End With
    MsgBox("File opened by: " & oDocument.Application.Name)
    oDocument.Range("A1") = "HEllo"
End Sub
End Class
```

My question is, how can I reference the opened document in the WebBrowser1_NavigateComplete2 method so I can automate excel to say display text in a specific cell.

Tried:

```
Option Explicit On
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports System.Data
Public Class CustomerService
      Dim oDocument As Object
      Dim oXL As Excel.Application
      Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
      Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
      Dim oRng As Excel.Range
      Private Sub CustomerService_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      WebBrowser1.Navigate(quoteFile)
End Sub
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NavigateComplete2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NavigateComplete2Event) Handles WebBrowser1.NavigateComplete2
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oXL As New Excel.Application
    oDocument = e.pDisp.Document
    objApp = oDocument
    objBooks = objApp.Workbooks
    objBook = objBooks.Add
    objSheets = objBook.Worksheets
    objSheet = objSheets(1)
    oXL = oDocument(.Document) 'with or without .Document
    With oDocument.Application.CommandBars("Standard")
        .Position = 4 '[msoBarFloating]
        .Visible = True
    End With
    MsgBox("File opened by: " & oDocument.Application.Name)
    objSheet.Range("A1") = "HEllo"
End Sub
End Class
```

With no luck. If you even have an inkling of a way to take this, I am all ears.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does changing the last line to include the sheet solve the problem?

```
oDocument.worksheets(1).Range("A1") = "HEllo"
```

---

Are you getting an error or is it just not doing anything?  Do you get your msgbox?

Comment: Your code does work. No errors, the msgbox did show. I guess I was doing this the hard way...lol